# how to scroll to the bottom of the page with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll

I have tried `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` after the page has loaded to no avail. It simply does nothing.

Why isn't it working? Is there another method I can use.

Answer (score 1):

scrollTo is usually the preferred way but not possible on every site.
Alternatively you can use this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
elem = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "html")
elem.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

However, I would much prefer requests instead of selenium.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to scroll the page with Selenium.
Additionally to

```py
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

You can try

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
html.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

But the most powerful way that normally works even when the previously methods will not is:
Locate some element out of the visible screen, maybe on the bottom of the page and apply on it the following

```py
bottom_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, bottom_element_locator)
bottom_element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

This originally intend to return you coordinates (`x`, `y`) of element on page, but also scroll down right to target element

Answer (score 1):

I found that when I tried to implement @bitflip's answer (which was one of the better I found for me), the page still hadn't loaded fully.

TL;DR: I was trying to get a post counter working, and wanted to make sure the page had fully loaded, with all the posts (approx ~100), before it started scraping.

I implemented a while loop, that would wait 3s before trying to find the footer each time (so the page would load more posts in that time). Still not pretty, but this seemed to work for me.

```
i = 1
while i <= 10:
    footer = driver.find_element(By.ID, "SITE_FOOTER")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", footer)
    print('It has scrolled ' + str(i) + ' times')
    print('Now waiting 3 seconds before repeating')
    time.sleep(3)
    i += 1
else:
    print('The script has finished scrolling to the bottom of the page.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to scroll to bottom of page is to emulate the CTRL + END key combination

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.END)
```