# Selenium cannot scrape all elements with same xpath, don't know if the page is not fully loaded?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this page the title and the price,
https://magnumbikes.com/collections/e-bikes?sort_by=best-selling,
but only half of the products can be collected (it stops at product Metro X),
not sure if it is the page is not fully loaded,
Please let me know or correct me thank you!
Here is my code:

```
URL='https://magnumbikes.com/collections/e-bikes?sort_by=best-selling'
#driver.maxmize_window()
driver.get(URL)
#There is a subscription window popping up for first time, refresh the page again!
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
titless=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div/div/h3[@class="collection-card__title h3"]')))

prices=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="collection-card__prices-inner"]/span')))


for i in range(0,len(titless)):
  print(titless[i].text)
  print(prices[i].text)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73792388/how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-the-page-with-selenium-python

Comment: tried driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body') still not working, it only scrapes until metro x.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get that information using Requests:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

big_list = []

for x in range(1, 3):
    r = s.get(f'https://magnumbikes.com/collections/e-bikes?page={x}&sort_by=best-selling')
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.select('div[class="collection-filter__item"]')
    for i in items:
        title = i.select_one('h3 a').get_text()    
        url = 'https://magnumbikes.com' + i.select_one('h3 a').get('href')
        big_list.append((title, url))
df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns=['Bike', 'Url'])
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Result in terminal:

|  | Bike | Url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Nomad | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-nomad |
| 1 | Pathfinder 350 | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-pathfinder-350 |
| 2 | Metro S | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-metro-s |
| 3 | Scout | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-scout |
| 4 | Payload | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-payload |
| 5 | Peak T7 | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-peak-t7 |
| 6 | Metro 750 | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-metro-750 |
| 7 | Pathfinder T | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-pathfinder-t |
| 8 | Ranger 1.0 | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-ranger |
| 9 | Low rider 1.0 | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-low-rider-2019 |
| 10 | Pathfinder 500 | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-pathfinder-500 |
| 11 | Cruiser 1.0 | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-cruiser-1-0 |
| 12 | Summit 27.5" | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-summit-27-5 |
| 13 | Metro X | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-metro-x |
| 14 | Peak T5 | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-peak-t5 |
| 15 | Premium 3 Low Step | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-premium-3-low-step |
| 16 | Navigator X | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-navigator-x |
| 17 | Cosmo X | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-cosmo-x |
| 18 | Cosmo+ | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-cosmo-1 |
| 19 | Cosmo S | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-cosmo-s |
| 20 | Low rider 2.0 | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-low-rider |
| 21 | Navigator S | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-navigator-s |
| 22 | Ranger 2.0 | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/ranger-2-0 |
| 23 | Premium 3 High Step | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-premium-3-high-step |
| 24 | Voyager | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-voyager |
| 25 | Cruiser 2.0 | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-cruiser |
| 26 | Cosmo | https://magnumbikes.com//collections/e-bikes/products/magnum-cosmo |

​
You can use Selenium if you wish - just observe the urls accessed (taken from Dev tools - Network tab) and the locators.

Comment: How do you know there are 2 pages?

Comment: https://magnumbikes.com/collections/e-bikes?sort_by=best-selling

Comment: magnumbikes.com/collections/e-bikes?page=2 sort_by=best-selling